# Need the URL coming in both attribute and content

Tags: xslt

My input is having URL, this needs to come in both attribute value and content value in the output using XSL:

My Input xml is:

```
<link>
<Url>http://tneb.gov/</Url>
</link>
```

XSL I Used as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="Url">
    <xsl:element name="xref">
      <xsl:attribute name="format">
        <xsl:text>html</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::link/Url"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output I get as:

```
<xref format="html" href="http://tneb.gov/"/>
```

But i need as:

```
<xref format="html" href="http://tneb.gov/">http://tneb.gov/</xref>
```

Please give me suggestion on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="Url">
    <xref format="html" href="{.}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xref>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Notes**:

- It's not necessary to use `xsl:element` if the name of the element is
  known - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#literal-result-element
- Learn about *attribute value templates*:
  https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates
- Learn about the *context item expression*:
  https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-context-item-expression

Comment: Thanks @michael. Its awesome